# How does client authenticate server with Auth0

Tags: c#, authentication, client, grpc, auth0

I'm developing a file hosting system in c# (clients and server) where users can upload/download and share files between each other.

I want to make this file hosting system as secure as possible so I'm assuming that the server and clients are not totally trustworthy and can be attacked by a malicious user.

Regarding authentication, I've been using Auth0 with GRPC to authenticate the clients to the server, but I'm having trouble understanding how the client knows who the server is.

In my understanding, Auth0 gives a token to the user that confirms he's identity, but how does the client know he's talking to the server?

Comment: Why not use HTTPS?

Comment: I edited the question, it was a bit confusing but essencially I'm interested in using Auth0, just confused about how it really works.

Comment: Re your edit: Auth0 is to provide you a mechanism for authenticating users, providing tokens to the client, and validating those tokens on the server. You know the tokens are valid because you have access to the secrets used to sign them.

Comment: You can probably go down the rabbit hole of how the tokens are validated by starting [here](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/access-tokens/validate-access-tokens) in the Auth0 documentation.

Comment: Thank you! So the client must assume the server is who he says he is, or does Auth0 provide confirmation for the server?

Comment: The client doesn't have to assume that. I don't see any reason why Auth0 would provide anything like that, to be honest. Use HTTPS. If the SSL certificate isn't valid from the client's perspective then the server isn't the real one.

Comment: Ok thank you! I'll do that